# Estimate a probability that the mean of k values selected randomly w/o replacement from a known non-normal-distributed set is between `a` and `b`

Tags: probability, distributions, mean

The goal is to roughly estimate the probability that a sum/average of k randomly selected values without replacement, taken from a known set, will be within the range [a, b]

So far the experiment was simulated and values were randomly selected thousands of times.
This is highly inefficient. Is there any method that is fast?

Comment: will the central limit theorem help you?

Comment: How large is your $k$, how large is your population, and how are the values within the population distributed? If both $k$ and the population size are "large", this sounds like a textbook case of the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: Hi @StephanKolassa, both k and the population can be "small" or "large". The goal is to know if it's likely or highly unlikely to get a k-sized sample with a mean in that range from that population. The distribution of positive values is sometimes exponential and sometimes many values are zero.

Comment: Hi @AturSams, it's been a while you asked this question, could you accept the provided anwswer or provide your own?

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure seems akin to a parametric bootstrap (though the bootstrap is generally performed with replacement).
You mention performing several thousands of times your resampling strategy, but it is generally admitted that in order to derive confidence bounds/standard errors $\mathcal{O}(100)$ samples are sufficient (cf [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Recommendations)). So you could already gain a factor of ~10x in terms of speed without changing your strategy. This naive resampling strategy might however be biased if your initial distribution is heavy tailed.

Otherwise as was mentioned in some comments, as long as your population size $N$ is large, $k$ is somewhat large, and $N>>k$ you can use the central limit theorem to assume a normal distribution on the error of your mean.

$N>>k$ basically means that even though you sample with replacement, chances of sampling twice the same object among the k objects is small. If this is not the case you cannot assume independence and identical distribution of your k sampled objects, then central limit theorem is not an option.